# Регулярное выражения для двух алфавитов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, интерпретатор

Я создаю свой интерпретатор на python. У меня есть токен NAME, отвечающий за имя переменной. Я задаю его следующим регулярным выражением:

```
NAME = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
```

Он без проблем обрабатывает строки вида:

```
a = 10
_b = "some_text"
test = 1
```

Я хочу ДОБАВИТЬ к латинскому алфавиту возможность использовать в качестве имени переменной буквы кириллицы, чтобы можно было обрабатывать строки вида:

```
ъ = 101
эюя = 'abc'
```

P.S.
если использовать такую регулярку: `NAME = r'[а-яА-Я_][а-яА-Я0-9_]*'`, то с кириллицей все работает, но ругается на латиницу.

Comment: а что мешает объединить эти две регулярки????

Comment: я не понимаю, как это сделать. пробовал так: ```NAME = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_][а-яА-Я_][а-яА-Я0-9_]*'``` - все сразу ломается. @Эникейщик

Comment: ну если наугад пробовать, то конечно вряд ли что получится. Нужно хотя бы элементарное понимание иметь. https://tproger.ru/articles/regexp-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

```
NAME = r'[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я_][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_]*'
```

P.S. спасибо комментаторам сверху, надеюсь их ответы вернутся им бумерангом в будущем.

Comment: Так вы почитали доки по регуляркам? Нашли в итоге решение? Ну так значит советы из комментариев вам помогли. Непонятно, чем вы недовольны ))

Comment: Нет, я нашел ответ с помощью доркинга. А такие комментарии - это просто отписка, тратящая время людей. Не знаешь/не можешь/не хочешь помогать - лучше не пиши ничего.
Даже сам сайт со мной согласен: "Этот сайт посвящён исключительно получению ответов. Это не форум для дискуссий. Здесь не место пустым разговорам." (c) @CrazyElf